# Swf object flash movie shows up in my thickbox

Tags: jquery, swfobject, thickbox

The swf movie sits on top of everything including the stuff that comes up in thickbox. I have no idea why this is happening.

This problem is only on IE7 (so far) but is likely to be in at least IE6 (I don't have IE6 to test on). BElow is the code I am using to embed my flash movie:

```
<div id="flash">You need the Flash Player to view this video.
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
/*<! */
var so = new SWFObject("mixed.swf", "flash", 529, 323, "9");
so.write("flash");
/*-->*/
</script>
```

I am using thickbox as I have other jQuery bits on the site. The url for the site is http://clients.bionic-comms.co.uk/fox/foxintouch-wp/issue/13/brand-highlights/

If someone could give me the answer I would be very appreciative. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out this solution.](http://thewichitacomputerguy.com/blog/z-index-flash-objects-thickbox-fix) See if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your div... you're missing the /div tag.

```
<div id="flash">You need the Flash Player to view this video.**</div>**
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("mixed.swf", "flash", 529, 323, "9");
so.write("flash");
</script>
```

Also, the SWFObject code shouldn't be placed inside the target div; this has caused problems for some people.

I see you're using SWFObject 1.5; I suggest upgrading to SWFObject 2.2, as it contains an important bugfix regarding memory leaks and Flash video. http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/